# X stuck when using OpenGL

Tags: xorg, opengl

On a stock Dell, RHEL 5.3, my X gets stuck when running any OpenGL program for more than a few seconds. After a few seconds, the screen freezes, and after another few seconds sometimes the screen turns white.

Any openGL program does that. I wrote a very simple program that uses only very basic polygon drawing, and it still causes X to freeze.

Killing X won't help it recover.

Both `dmesg` and the X log don't show any special errors except of

```
(WW) AIGLX 3D driver claims not to support visual 0x23
(WW) AIGLX 3D driver claims not to support visual 0x24
...
(WW) AIGLX 3D driver claims not to support visual 0x32
```

Similar error message appears after I execute an glut OpenGL program.

What could be the trouble? How can I further debug the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a problem with your video driver. Download the latest driver for you video card from the vendor's site if it's Nvidia or ATI/AMD, otherwise look for supported OpenGL extensions in your current drivers.

Comment: How can I revert the driver to a software renderer, in order to make sure this is the driver's fault? I'm not entirely sure how to do that, and I'll be glad for references (googling for linux opengl software acceleration didn't hlep).

Comment: Well, if you switch to another driver which does not know 3D, you will not be able to test OpengGL... Please tell us what kind of video card you have, so we can guide you to some specific tutorials/examples. Did you update your driver to the latest version? If you have Intel video card, you probably have to stick with the drivers bundled in your Linux distribution or wait for an update. Intel cards also have some OpenGL issues, check their bugtracking site. It may also be a X configuration issue, try to disable DRI and Compositing in the xorg.conf.